# I want to use php preg_match function to validate score

Tags: php

the requirement
-Only two decimal places allowed.
-Values before the decimal point must be at least 1 number.
-Example: 5.09
-return turn and false

Comment: show your code, not homework description

Comment: <?php
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name) {
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;      
}
?>

<?php
if () {
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;      
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
$score = 5.09;
$result = (bool) preg_match("/^[0-9]+(\.[1-9]{1})+([0-9]{1})?$/", $score);
var_dump($result);
```

`.[1-9]{1}` means 1 character after decimal `(.)` must start from 1